# phing: get last commit ID (revision) and use it as a phing attribute

Tags: svn, deployment, phing

I'm trying to get the latest revision ID from my SVN project using Phing.
What I'm trying to do is the following:

- get latest revision/commit number
  from svn
- store this revision number    as an
  attribute (so that I can use    this
  to append it to the archive I'm
  already creating using phing)

I don't have a working copy on my server where phing is running, so I cannot use the Phing SvnLastRevisionTask.

Comment: I can't imagine how can you get the latest revision without a working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we found it ourselves and did it as follows:

```
<exec command="svn info http://user:pass@localhost/repos/trunk | grep Revision  | awk '{print $2}'" outputProperty="svn.lastrevision" />
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in way to get the [latest revision](http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#SvnLastRevisionTask) as well

```
<svnlastrevision
    svnpath="${svn.path}"
    workingcopy="${outputdir}"
    propertyname="svn.lastrevision"/>
```